# What is the name for these help files, and how can I browse them out of program?

Tags: windows, help-files

There is a very specific type of help file in Windows that has been around for decades now, yet I'm not quite sure what they're called, or how to browse them.
They're often heavily text oriented and hierarchical, and they have the same GUI layout across all programs. I have a picture below of what I mean. From what I remember they may be linked to DLLs? Not certain.

What's the formal name for this sort of help file, and how can I open them out of program?
[image]

Comment: The tool HH.exe (html-help) does still exist in my actual Windows 10. Use it to open/run compiled windows help files with the extension `.chm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/8205/how-to-view-chm-files

Comment: @LotPings this should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [wikipedia article on Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help)

The tool HH.exe (html-help) does still exist in my actual Windows 10.

Use it to open/run compiled windows help files with the extension `.chm`